# call function from other file python

Tags: python, function, class, object, attributes

I need to display the results of values that has been stored into a list. The list is stored into a class within a class that it is safe in another file.

Basically on the other file to return the values, I used the following code:

```
...
def __init__(self):
    self.employee_list = []

def addEmployee(self, name, number, years_worked,salary):
    newEmployee = employee.Employee(name,number,years_worked,salary)
    self.employee_list.append(newEmployee)

def printEmployee(self):
    for eachEmployee in self._employee_list:
        print("Name",name)
        print("Number",number)
        print("Years Worked", years_worked)
        print("Salary:", salary)
```

(The values are also sent to another file that contains a class and attributes regarding the employee)

Then, on the main file, in order to call the function printEmployee to display all the data, I wrote this:

```
from staff import Staff
mystaff = Staff()
print("Welcome to my Staff Management Program")
print(choices)

elif choice == "D":
    for emp in mystaff.employee_list:
        print(emp)
```

Is shows this:

```
<employee.Employee object at 0x02A2F6B0>
```

Can I have help please?
Many thanks.

Comment: Somehow your first piece of code does not look right. It look like a class but the class definition is missing and the indentation is not OK. Can you fix that.

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted the wrong code. Please check now :)

Comment: The code is big, that's why I thought in cut some pieces of code that isn't relevant for this question.

Comment: @Ana Please review the answer so that if it was not helpful i can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you should use `printEmployee` instead of do manually printing:

```
...
elif choice == "D":
    mystaff.printEmployee()
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it displays: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SOFIA\Desktop\New folder\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    mystaff.printEmployee()
  File "C:\Users\SOFIA\Desktop\New folder\staff.py", line 21, in printEmployee
    for eachEmployee in self._employee_list:
AttributeError: 'Staff' object has no attribute '_employee_list'
>>>

Comment: Fix this line:`for eachEmployee in self._employee_list:` on `for eachEmployee in self.employee_list:`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee:  
    def __init__(self):
        self.employee_list = []

    def addEmployee(self, name, number, years_worked,salary):
        newEmployee = [name,number,years_worked,salary]
        self.employee_list.append(newEmployee)

    def printEmployee(self):
        for eachEmployee in self._employee_list:
            print("Name",name)
            print("Number",number)
            print("Years Worked", years_worked)
            print("Salary:", salary)

emp_obj = Employee()
emp_obj.addEmployee('Monty', '007', '13', '50000')
emp_obj.addEmployee('Max', '008', '3', '30000')
emp_obj.addEmployee('Ana', '009', '7', '70000')


from m1 import Staff
mystaff = Staff()
print("Welcome to my Staff Management Program")
choice = raw_input("Enter your choice:")

if choice == "D":
    mystaff.employee_list = emp_obj.employee_list
    for emp in mystaff.employee_list:
        print("Employee Name: {}, Number: {}, Years worked: {}, Salary: {}").format(emp[0],emp[1],emp[2],emp[3],)
```

Result :

```
Welcome to my Staff Management Program
Enter your choice:D
Employee Name: Monty, Number: 007, Years worked: 13, Salary: 50000
Employee Name: Max, Number: 008, Years worked: 3, Salary: 30000
Employee Name: Ana, Number: 009, Years worked: 7, Salary: 70000
```

You should try to achieve this by `inheritance`. That would be the correct approach in your case.